# search for multiple occurrences of a string and get the values to an array

Tags: powershell

I need to search for multiple occurrences of a string "2-High" in a web page and get the values to an array using powershell. The string is inside cell of a table

```
foreach($table in $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("table"))
{

    foreach($tr in $table.getElementsByTagName("tr"))
    {

        $trval=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")|?{$_.innerText -eq '2 -     High' }

        if($trval -eq $null)
        {
            write-host "not found"
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($td in $tr.getElementsByTagName("td"))
            {

                $htmlResults += $td.geElementsByValue

                $htmlResults
                if($htmlResults -eq $null)
                {
                    write-host " arraylist empty"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the result as "arraylist empty"

Comment: The line `$htmlResults += $td.geElementsByValue` is invalid. Is that a typo in your question? What do you want to append to `$htmlResults` there?

Comment: I need to get the innerText of all the cells of the row where the cell "2-High" is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$htmlResults = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName('tr') `
                 | ? { $_.innerText -match '2-High' } `
                 | % { $_.children | select -Expand innerText }
```

Comment: I tried.. But I am getting the `innertext` of all the rows of the table into the array.. it is not selecting the rows with value 'High'. An error `Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the val
ue of argument "obj" to a non-null value.` is shown

Comment: @user3750784: The code in my example is filtering rows containing the string `2-High`, not just `High`. Please update your question with your modified code and sample HTML data.

Comment: @user3750784: Also, please accept an answer only if it actually solves your problem.

Comment: it is not selecting the rows with value 'High'.every rows are selected

Comment: @user3750784: Again: please update the code in your question and provide sample input data.

Comment: This is the code I have used `$a = Get-Content "url"`
`$htmlResults= $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr") `
                 `| where { $_.innerText -match "2 - High" } `
               `| select -ExpandProperty innerText `
              `$htmlResults` I am getting the values of all the rows of the table.After printing the rows i'm getting the values of the selected row `2-High' printed

Comment: @user3750784: For the 3rd time: please **update the code IN YOUR QUESTION** and **provide SAMPLE INPUT DATA**.

Comment: It worked... I used with multiple matching conditions.. `$htmlResults= $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")`
                 `| where { ($_.innerText -match "2 - High") -and($_.innerText -notmatch "Work in Progress") }`
                 `| select -ExpandProperty innerText`... It is now displaying only rows with columns '2-High' and without 'Work in Progress' Thank You